# Schedule 1, Other Income: How to override in TurboTax

Tags: united-states, income-tax, turbotax, audit

I have other income that is listed on Schedule 1.

Schedule 1 Form line 8 state list type and amount.

Turbo Tax enters "other income 1099-misc".

I want to override the text and put my text in that will describe this "other income" as I believe this would be beneficial for return (potential audit flag removed).

If possible, what are the steps to override the text that Turbo Tax forces onto line 8 of Schedule 1.

Answer (score 1):

You could try deleting your form 1099-MISC from Turbotax, so that the software does not automatically categorize that income.

Then, look for a question in Turbotax that asks you about Other Income. There ought to be a way to manually enter income that has no 1099. It should work to enter the income here even though you do have a 1099.

Comment: Worth noting that you still need to file the 1099 when you file all your other tax documents, and e-filing with Turbotax after doing this will NOT file the deleted 1099.

Comment: paulj may not have received a 1099, which is why he doesn't want TurboTax to assume that he did.

Comment: Indeed. If no 1099 was filed then you would manually enter the income. I was just pointing out that if a 1099 was filed by the employer, you would need to include it in your individual filing.

Comment: @GOATNine 1099 is not normally  filed by the recipient with his or her tax return (unlike W-2, which *is* included in the tax return filing).

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica I was unaware, thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

There are a handful of cases where I have had to adjust information in Turbotax.

There are two ways to enter numbers into the software: question (step-by-step), or directly on the form. There is button on the top to switch modes.

I took a quick look at Schedule 1 in the software. Schedule 1 has a worksheet that feeds it the numbers. In fact line 8 has another worksheet because what can go in there can come from many sources that might be mentioned on other forms.

I am not sure if the text in that line can be modified, but that is where I would start.